# 70+ VM migration from ESXi 4.1 free to Hyper-V

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, migration, hyper-v-server-2012

We have 70+ VM's (all Windows except Elastix PBX and 1 more LAMP server) on 2 hosts running free ESXi 4.1, backed by a Dell PowerVault MD3220i SAN. I am adding another host and another PowerVault MD enclosure to the group. Because of cost considerations we would like to move to Hyper-V 2012. There are 2 options as I understand:

1. Move all VM's to Hyper-V in one go. I don't know how long this would take. Can this be done over a weekend?
2. Setup the additional SAN and host on Windows and keep moving the VM's over a period of time

Would appreciate any suggestions. Will there be issues with Elastix PBX and Hyper-V?

Thank you for the responses. To make the question more focused:

1. Does anyone have experience running Elastix PBX and Apache LAMP stack on Hyper-V in production?
2. If I move the VM's over time, we would have a mix of esxi and hyper-v hosts + some LUN's in the 3220i will be vmfs and others will be CSV. Is that a problem?
3. We do not use Active Directory. Are we forced to move to one?

Comment: A point of clarification: You can't simply move the virtual machines from vSphere to Hyper-V. You'll have to convert them.

Comment: It seems like the cost of vSphere licensing (Essentials **$600** or Essentials Plus **$5000**) is worth it versus the time and complexity of migrating 70 virtual machines to Hyper-V.

Comment: To address your specific questions: `1.` Does anyone have experience running Elastix PBX and Apache LAMP stack on Hyper-V in production? - I can't imagine it's any different than running them on vSphere. You're simply changing the hypervisor host. `2.` If I move the VM's over time, we would have a mix of esxi and hyper-v hosts + some LUN's in the 3220i will be vmfs and others will be CSV. Is that a problem? - No. Why would it be? `3.` We do not use Active Directory. Are we forced to move to one? - No. Why would you? There's no requirement for the Hyper-V host to be a member of an AD domain.

Comment: @joeqwerty, if the Hyper-V hosts are to form a cluster, AD is a requirement.

Comment: Right, but I didn't get that from the OP's question. Good for him to know though so thanks for the assist.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. We will end up with a total of 4 hosts  with quad sockets and 2 SAN's from the existing 3 hosts and 1 SAN so the esxi pricing is substantial. We don't mind administering them individually with vsphere but would like (not must have) to have live migration and incremental backup. Now I have to evaluate if it is worth the hassle...

Answer (score 3):

[There's a tool made for this very thing, called the Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn873998.aspx) (currently at version 3.0).  As to your questions about time and the best way to do this, those are highly variable, environment-specific things you'll have to figure out on your own.  Shouldn't be too hard - pick some typical VMs, time their conversions, extrapolate how long it will take, and pad your estimate a bit, then see if that fits into your maintenance window, or if you have to move the VMs in a more staged fashion.

Comment: I've also used Disk2VHD, but I don't remember why I used one over the other. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656415.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a step by step migration guide at http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/03/24/step-by-step-migrating-from-vmware-to-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2012.aspx. ; which uses MVMC.  Option 3 is to start with option 2 and once you've observed some conversion times, see if option 1 is feasible.

As far as your other questions go,

1. Can't comment- no XP
2. they are separate luns- I can't see a problem there
3. yes - failover clusters require AD, but the DC can be a VM on one of the hosts outside of the cluster, but do not make it HA, or place it on shared storage. Also make sure to configure the Auto-Start Action, so your DC boots up with the host.

Comment: @nid15: As Jim B stated in his answer and as Massimo stated in his comment, if you plan to create a Hyper-V Failover Cluster between two or more Hyper-V hosts then AD is a requirement. If you plan to just deploy a single Hyper-V host then AD isn't a requirement.